# .htaccess redirection to prerender on API

Tags: django, facebook, .htaccess

I'm developing a Single Page Application using AngularJS in parallel with a Django REST API.

**What do I want to do?**

I want that when the user shares some post on facebook all meta tags are read property by facebook crawlers (bots).

**The issue**

AngularJS dynamically generates its content through two-way data binding, and Facebook crawler couldn't read it properly. I've tried to use prerender.io, without any success. That's why I decided to create an django API endpoint that has the only goal of rendering a blank page only with the shareable metatags. If the user arrives there, he'll be redirected to the correct post.

DJANGO CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Prerender</title>

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID_HERE">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{property.description}}">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{property.title}}">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.therentalmoose.com/property/{{property.id}}">
    <meta property="og:image"
          content="https://www.therentalmoose.com:8000/static/images/properties/{{property.id}}/0.jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="488">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="931">


</head>
<body>

  <script>window.location.replace('https://www.therentalmoose.com/property/{{property.id}}');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

** Solution that I'm trying (without success so far) **

I'm trying to configure my .htaccess file to redirect a facebook crawler bot when doing a request to **https://www.therentalmoose.com/property/2**
to **https://www.therentalmoose.com:8000/prerender/property/2** 
That's where my metatag information is properly configured. Note that "2" is a dynamic variable and should change on every request.

So far, my .htaccess file looks like this (its located at /var/www/html on my server)

```
  <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
    RewriteRule ^property/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ http://www.therentalmoose.com:8000/prerender/property/$2 [P,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index

    #this condition for crawlers not to interfere with normal access
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)

    #this rule for html5 mode and friendly urls without the #
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

</ifModule>
```

**The error***

When trying the first url on facebook debugger tool, it throws an 404 error. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.therentalmoose.com%2Fproperty%2F2%2F

However, if I try to crawl directly the API prerender endpoint, everything works:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.therentalmoose.com%3A8000%2Fprerender%2Fproperty%2F2

Could someone give me a hand?

I've being trying to solve this "simple" problem for many hours so far with many different approachs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Prerender.io had lots of problems in the past and I don't really trust it anymore. I'd really recommend to use Rendora https://github.com/rendora/rendora instead. It's FOSS, self hosted, doesn't depend on your frontend and backend stacks, uses internal caching and much more lightweight.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion